# iPhone Configuration Software/Application for Windows or Mac OS X

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm, configuration-profiles

Is there any application that would allow you to manage and configure your iPhone? (i.e. desktop screen, desktop folders, icon names, settings, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can manage and configure your iPhone using the free app "Apple Configurator 2" from the macOS App Store.

You can read more about it on Apple's support page:

https://support.apple.com/da-dk/apple-configurator

It won't necessarily allow you to change icon names, though, as they're generally not configurable.